# функция не видит переменную php

Tags: php

echo functionname(array("first"=>12,"sec"=>45,"third"=>23,"forth"=>55));

```
$array = array (12, -4.24);
$sum = 0;

function functionname($array){

  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

       $sum += $value;
      echo $key."<br>";
      echo "sum ".$sum."<br>";
  }
  return $sum / count ($array);
}
```

//переменная $sum в функцие не определяется

Comment: а где вызов функции?

Comment: echo"<br>".functionname(array("first"=>12,"sec"=>45,"third"=>23,"forth"=>55));

Comment: половина ответа содержится в самом вопросе. _"не видит"_ => область видимости переменных. Знакомо вам такое понятие?

Comment: если я правильно понял то  все, что вне функций – это глобальная область видимости, все, что внутри функций – локальная область видимости. так вот в функции пишу global $sum но значение переменной оно не видит, как будто просто создает новую переменную без значение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$sum` - нужно перенести в вашу функцию, функция её не видит

```
function functionname(&$sum, $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        $sum += $value;
        echo $key . "<br>";
        echo "sum " . $sum . "<br>";
    }
    return $sum / count($array);
}

$sum = 0;
$array = [12, -4.24];

echo functionname($sum, $array);
```

Comment: ну так понятно ,но может мне надо $sum н нескольких отдельных функций использовать ?  нужно ее объявить вне функции

Comment: тогда можно передавать её в функцию, как параметр

Comment: @MiqayelPetrosyan поправил функцию